# Goutte can not submit the form

Tags: php, goutte

I am facing a problem. I am trying to submit a form with goutte. But its not working.
This is the website url https://www.petakids.com/spotlight/free-peta-kids-stickers/

and this is my code

```
        $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'https://www.petakids.com/spotlight/free-peta-kids-stickers/');
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('btnSubmit')->form();
        $crawler = Goutte::submit($form,array(
            'strFName' => 'sayed',
            'strLName' => 'sayed',
            'strCompanyName' => 'sayed',
            'strAddr1' => 'sayed',
            'strCity' => 'sayed',
            'strState187' => 'AK',
            'strEmail' => 'reovilsayed@gmail.com',
            'strCountry' => 'Albania',
            'strZip' => 'sayed',
            'strPhone' => 1926184022,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.petakids.com/spotlight/free-peta-kids-stickers/');
$form = $crawler->filter('#PETAKidsFreeStickers')->first()->form();

$crawler = $client->submit($form, array(
    'strFName' => 'sayed',
    'strLName' => 'sayed',
    'strCompanyName' => 'sayed',
    'strAddr1' => 'sayed',
    'strCity' => 'sayed',
    'strState' => 'AE',
    'strEmail' => 'reovilsayed@gmail.com',
    'strCountry' => 'Albania',
    'strStateOther' => 'NONE',
    'strZip' => '8440732',
    'strPhone' => 1926184022,
));
```

Greetings